# Create SQLite table before compile

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Is it possible to create a default "table" (not programatically) in sqlite and have eclipse compile it into the apk? Basically I want a table file that the program can then later access to get information from.

Edit: Just to add more information: What I want to do is create a file that can be added in the "res" folder that has a table (containing all the values I wish to add to the DB). These will be treated as "constants" and I will use the "KEY" value to link them to the other tables that will be done within my program.

However I apologize, I did not originally find the answer to my question. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem. You should create first the data base, then add in your proyect in the assests. So you have to extends from SqliteHelper. Then do what ever wanna do.

Comment: Sorry, I may not have explained exacly what I wanted. What I want to do is create a file that can be added in the "res" folder (containing all the values I wish to add to the DB).